# AngularJS 2 Variable Import

Tags: angularjs, angular, import, structure, project

I wonder if it is Possible to save a part of my import URL as a constant Variable in some external file.
What i have in mind:

Project structure:

```
Project
|
+--moduleA
|  |
|  +--src
|     |
|     +--objects
|        |
|        +--common
|           |
|           +--car.ts
|
+--moduleB
   |
   +--src
      |
      +--objects
         |
         +--common
            |
            +--parkingLot.ts
```

In the tsconfig.json the property `baseUrl` is set to `.`

So if i want to use the `Car.ts` component in my `parkingLot` component i have to do this : `import { car } from 'moduleA/src/objects/common/car.ts'`.

What i want to use is this : `import { car } from object_path + 'car'` (while object_path contains `moduleA/src/objects/common/`)

If i change the project structure from `moduleA` the Import would not work anymore and i would have to change each import which refers to moduleA. Is there a way to store as a constant in some file and only import this file then ?

Comment: Why do you keep changing your project structure.. Angular have a style guide.. its explain well how you should setup your project..

Comment: @AbdelRaoof If the project grows it might get confusing and need some more structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot concatenate variable with the string in the import statement. Angular will throw a String literal error unless if you want to define the global setting and use it later in the class, you can.

this line will throw  `String literal Error`

```
import { car } from object_path + 'car'
```

The example below will define the global setting and you can use it anywhere in your app

**global.ts**

```
export class AppSettings {
    public static API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost/api/';  
}
```

**car.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AppSettings} from '../global';

@Component({
    selector: 'car-component',
    templateUrl: 'car.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['car.component.css']
})

export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
    endpoint:string;

    constructor() {
        this.endpoint = AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT;
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```